# Creating Hash-Map Clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I have 2 list let say list of user (list-usr) and (usr-index), i want to create hash-map from these list much like

```
(def list-usr [196 186 244])
(def idx-usr  [0 1 2])
```

how can i form `(hash-map {196 0 186 1 244 2})` from 2 list ?

Comment: looks like you need `zipmap`

Comment: :v omg thanks, i thought any "zip" keyword is missing from clojure documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ByanJati

The function for taking two vectors and interleaving to create hash map is [zipmap](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/zipmap).

It should provide what you want, keep in mind that you will be using integers as the keys:

```
(zipmap list-usr idx-usr)
```